# Typing with custom font in custom keyboard

Tags: android

Hi,
I am new to Android,and I will be happy to get your help to something I am looking for a while.
How can I write my own font by typing at a custom keyboard.
My goal is doing a custom keyword that can writes to peoples with various fonts from the default.
for example: when someone writes to his friend in whatsapp , I want that the font that will be written will be a custom font and the friend who got this will see the same custom font that sent to him.
 Is it possible in Android? and if not why? 
right now, I didn't see a way to do that.
 but  I thought on a workaround: to catch "on typing" event and change the clipboard to the custom font and pasting it. but I don't know how to put in clipboard this font.. 
thank you all

Comment: Please mark as answered (click the checkmark) if my response was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. In most cases, fonts are defined by the programmer in their application or by the system for system UI related things (status bar text, settings menu text).

Users can not customize the font of an application that isn't theirs (unless you decompile their APKs by hand and modify XML files, but that is a whole different can of worms).

Furthermore, font information isn't typically stored inside the clipboard. Only raw text (in most cases, that is, especially in the case of the universal app compatibility you want to achieve). The only exception to this is rich text (used in apps like gmail for only specific things like the compose view) but rich text input isn't accepted by standard textedit controls (again, something which you would have no control over).